# Modify certain values in a data frame by indirect reference to the columns

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, rlang

I'm wrangling some data where we sort fails into bins and compute limited yields for each sort bin by lot.

**I have a meta table that describes the sort bins.** *The rows are arranged in ascending test order and some of the sort labels come in with non-syntactic names.*

```
sort_tbl <- tibble::tribble(~weight,   ~label,
                                  0, "fail A",
                                  0, "fail B",
                                  0, "fail C",
                                100,   "pass")
> sort_tbl
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  weight  label
   <dbl>  <chr>
1      0 fail A
2      0 fail B
3      0 fail C
4    100   pass
```

**I have a data table of limited yield by sort bin** with one row per lot and one col for each sort bin. Because this table was constructed from a transposition we get instances where a particular sort never occurred for a lot and the resulting value is `NA`. *Note that the columns in this table are arranged in descending test order.*

```
yld_tbl <- tibble::tribble(  ~lot, ~pass, ~`fail C`, ~`fail B`, ~`fail A`,
                           "lot1",    NA,        NA,      0.00,        NA,
                           "lot2",    NA,      0.00,      0.80,        NA,
                           "lot3",  0.49,        NA,      0.50,      0.98,
                           "lot4",  0.70,      0.95,      0.74,      0.99)
> yld_tbl
# A tibble: 4 x 5
    lot  pass `fail C` `fail B` `fail A`
  <chr> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1  lot1    NA       NA     0.00       NA
2  lot2    NA     0.00     0.80       NA
3  lot3  0.49       NA     0.50     0.98
4  lot4  0.70     0.95     0.74     0.99
```

Some of the missing values imply a limited yield of 100% while others reflect an undefined value because we are zero yield earlier in the flow. **My task is to replace the former group of `NA`'s with `1.00` as appropriate.**

One algorithm to accomplish this works left to right (descending test order) replacing `NA` with `1.00` if the subsequent limited yield is not `NA`. In the first row of the example data set, we don't change `fail C` since `pass` is missing. But we do replace `fail A` with `1.00` since `fail B` is not missing.

The correct example output would be:

```
> fill_ones(yld_tbl, sort_tbl)
# A tibble: 4 x 5
    lot  pass `fail C` `fail B` `fail A`
  <chr> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1  lot1    NA       NA     0.00     1.00
2  lot2    NA     0.00     0.80     1.00
3  lot3  0.49     1.00     0.50     0.98
4  lot4  0.70     0.95     0.74     0.99
```

Comment: I don't manage to get how you fill the 1. could you explicitly gives the conditions ?

Comment: @denis I updated the question to explain this more explicitly.

Comment: What will happen ic case of two subsequent `NA`s, e.g., will `lot5    NA     0.95       NA       NA` become `lot5    NA     0.95     1.00     1.00`?

Comment: @Uwe, yes, the later `NA`'s in your example would become `1.00`. But the implied pass yield is `0.95` so the example line would need to read: `lot5 0.95 0.95 NA NA` becomes `lot5 0.95 0.95 1.00 1.00`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem becomes a bit easier if you think of it as "first replace all the NAs with 1, then replace all 1s after the first 0 with NA."

Here are two approaches, one using matrix operations and one using dplyr.

---

In the matrix approach, you'd extract the values as a numeric matrix, use `apply` to find the positions that need to be replaced with NA, and return them.

```
# extract as a matrix, with left-to-right bins
m <- as.matrix(yld_tbl[, sort_tbl$label])

# replace NAs with 1
m[is.na(m)] <- 1

# find 1s happening after a zero in each row
after_zero <- t(apply(m == 0, 1, cumsum)) & (m == 1)

# replace them with NA
m[after_zero] <- NA

# return them in the table
yld_tbl[, sort_tbl$label] <- m
```

---

Using dplyr/tidyr, you'd first `gather()` the columns (using `arrange()` to put them in the desired order), replace the NAs (the `group_by`/`mutate` is accomplishing the same thing as `apply` above), and `spread` them back into a wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

yld_tbl %>%
  gather(label, value, -lot) %>%
  arrange(lot, match(label, sort_tbl$label)) %>%
  replace_na(list(value = 1)) %>%
  group_by(lot) %>%
  mutate(value = ifelse(cumsum(value == 0) > 0 & value == 1, NA, value)) %>%
  spread(label, value)
```

Note that unlike the matrix-based approach, this does not preserve the ordering of the columns.

Comment: Thanks!  These look like interesting approaches. Both avoid looping over the columns explicitly. Which I prefer. The incoming data started as a vertical column so I can do the `replace_na()` operation on the way in with `spread(..., fill = 1.00)`. And I have a table of column names in order so re-ordering the columns is just a `select(lot, !!!syms(sort_tbl$label))`.

Comment: I'm trying to get my head around what `cumsum(value == 0)` is doing. The numeric vector `yld_tbl$value` will be converted to a logical vector. I guess `cumsum()` coerces this back to numeric because of the `> 0`? So we add the number of zeros in a lot and if there are any we replace the `value == 1` entries with `NA`. That's pretty slick!

Comment: That’s right- ‘cumsum(x == 0)’ would be the number of zeroes so far, and ‘cumsum(x == 0) > 0’ means “there has been at least one zero”. It’s a handy idiom to say “after the first such-and-such, do this”

Answer (score 0):

To generate the output table I have written the following function:

```
library(rlang)
library(dplyr)

fill_ones <- function(df, meta) {
  fail_labels <- meta[meta$weight == 0, ]$label
  last_val <- NULL
  for ( i in length(fail_labels):1) {
    if (is.null(last_val)) last_val <- df$pass
    else last_val <- eval_tidy(sym(fail_labels[[i+1]]), df)
    this_name <- sym(fail_labels[[i]])
    this_val  <- eval_tidy(this_name, df)
    this_val[intersect(which(!is.na(last_val)), which(is.na(this_val)))] <- 1
    df <- mutate(df, !!!new_definition(this_name, this_val))
  }
  df
}
```

This function loops over the fail sorts defined in `meta` and computes changes to the corresponding column in the data table `df`.

Calls to `sym(fail_labels[[i]])` lookup the name of each column and `eval_tidy(..., df)` extracts the corresponding vector in the data frame.

The expression `intersect(which(!is.na(last_val)), which(is.na(this_val)))` defines the subset of `NA`'s that will be replaced by a `1.00`.

The entire column is over-written with new values using `mutate()`. To reduce the amount of quoting and unquoting I use `new_definition()` rather than `:=`.

I'm not convinced I've reached the simplest syntax for indirectly referring to columns in a data table. Having non-syntactic names doesn't help. Also, we only need to modify a limited number of `NA`'s yet this solution re-writes every data entry column by column. I haven't hit upon a good syntax to avoid this (without turning to `data.table`).

*If anyone has a better approach I would love to hear it.*

Answer (score 0):

Following OP's approach to fill in missing 1.00 from left to right, this can be implemented using `melt()`, `dcast()` and `rleid()`:

```
library(data.table)
mDT <- melt(setDT(yld_tbl), id.var = "lot")
mDT[
  mDT[, grp := rleid(is.na(value)), by = lot][, .I[is.na(value) & grp > 1]]
  , value := 1][
    , dcast(.SD, lot ~ variable)]
```

> ```
>     lot pass fail C fail B fail A
> 1: lot1   NA     NA   0.00   1.00
> 2: lot2   NA   0.00   0.80   1.00
> 3: lot3 0.49   1.00   0.50   0.98
> 4: lot4 0.70   0.95   0.74   0.99
> 5: lot5 0.95   0.95   1.00   1.00
> ```

#### Data

```
yld_tbl <- tibble::tribble(  ~lot, ~pass, ~`fail C`, ~`fail B`, ~`fail A`,
                             "lot1",    NA,        NA,      0.00,        NA,
                             "lot2",    NA,      0.00,      0.80,        NA,
                             "lot3",  0.49,        NA,      0.50,      0.98,
                             "lot4",  0.70,      0.95,      0.74,      0.99,
                             "lot5",  0.95,      0.95,        NA,        NA)
```

Note the additional `"lot5"` row.

Comment: Thanks. I don't personally use DT yet but it's good to have an example in that syntax.

Comment: Wow. amazing combo.