# dplyr | group_by vs anti_join | most efficient way

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a big data set but here I am creating a sample data which has same data wrangling problem

data

```
brand=c('MS', 'Google', 'Apple', 'MS', 'FB', 'Apple', 'Oracle')
product=c('Window', 'Search', 'Iphone', 'Window', 'Network', 'Iphone', 'DB')
isExist=c('Yes', 'Yes', NA, 'No', NA, 'Yes', NA)
df= data.frame(brand, product, isExist)
```

this data look like this

```
   brand product isExist
1     MS  Window     Yes
2 Google  Search     Yes
3  Apple  Iphone    <NA>
4     MS  Window      No
5     FB Network    <NA>
6  Apple  Iphone     Yes
7 Oracle      DB    <NA>
```

now I want the rows based on brand and product (composite key) which does have NA entries for isExist and does not have any other rows for same composite key which has values i.e. it should return FB, Oracle but not Apple as one of the row (row no 6) have value in isExist

I am achieving it using anti_join, here the code

```
library(dplyr)
testWithData <- df %>% filter(!is.na(isExist))
testWithoutData <- df %>% filter(is.na(isExist))
final <- unique(anti_join(testWithoutData, testWithData, by = c('brand', 'product')))
```

Output

```
   brand product isExist
1     FB Network    <NA>
2 Oracle      DB    <NA>
```

This solution is working but it takes too much time, I know its not most efficient way. I feel group_by and filter can do some magic but I am not sure how I write the query, can someone please help me in this regard

Comment: I don't have time to work it out just now but am fairly certain there is an elegant solution using cumsum(x == 0) after you convert the NA's to a countable value (e.g. 1).  See top answer to my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47289543/modify-certain-values-in-a-data-frame-by-indirect-reference-to-the-columns/47310247?noredirect=1#comment81573872_47310247

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
brand=c('MS', 'Google', 'Apple', 'MS', 'FB', 'Apple', 'Oracle')
product=c('Window', 'Search', 'Iphone', 'Window', 'Network', 'Iphone', 'DB')
isExist=c('Yes', 'Yes', NA, 'No', NA, 'Yes', NA)
df= data.frame(brand, product, isExist)

library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(brand) %>%                     # for each brand
  filter(sum(!is.na(isExist)) == 0) %>%   # get sum of values that are not NA and keep rows where the sum is 0
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 2 x 3
#      brand product isExist
#     <fctr>  <fctr>  <fctr>
#   1     FB Network    <NA>
#   2 Oracle      DB    <NA>
```

The above process can be understood if you run this step by step (first 2 rows, then first 3, etc.)

```
df %>% 
  arrange(brand) %>%                          # order brands to have a better visualisation
  group_by(brand) %>%                         # group by brand and create (on the background) 5 sub-datasets based on each brand (see the Groups: brand [5])
  mutate(Counter = sum(!is.na(isExist))) %>%  # count how many times you have non NA values, based on a brand, and add it as a column while keeping all rows (this is like counting and joining back to the original dataset at the same time)
  filter(Counter == 0) %>%                    # keep only rows with Counter = 0 (those are the ones with only NA values)
  ungroup()                                   # forget the grouping
```

Comment: thanks, this query works. Can you please help me to understand
After filter, it only pick the value which does not have NA so how FB and Oracle came in picture which has NA values

Comment: is it like is.na only work within scope of sum so it will not give any exception and it does not filter the main query, I am from OOPS and SQL background so thinking in that way, now I understand the query ...I am impressed the way you handle this problem ..great

Comment: SQL background helps a lot understand the data manipulation processes of a dataframe using `dplyr`. The commands are simple and they describe what they do (eg, filter, mutate, arrange, group_by, etc.)

Comment: yes, I got it. I was only confused if is.na filter the main query then how the rows having NA are returned. once I think deeply then find its within scope of sum only

Comment: I've added a bit more informative process in the end of my answer. Run this step by step to better understand it. I can remove it if you prefer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160761/discussion-between-vineet-and-antoniosk).